# Codeigniter url routes

Tags: codeigniter, url, routes

I have the following in my codeigniter routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "home";
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['(:any)'] = "page";
$route['about'] = "about";
$route['content/edit'] = "content/edit";
$route['content'] = "content";
```

localhost/anything routes to page controller like it should. localhost/about and localhost/content route to the about controller and content controller like they should.  But localhost/content/edit routes to page controller.  I need it to route to the edit function in my content controller.  How do I accomplish that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will always take precedence over lower ones.

I am guessing this is why it's routing to the page controller.

Try moving;

```
$route['content/(:any)'] = "content";
```

Above:

```
$route['(:any)'] = "page";
```